# Blazor 8 united + Azure b2c

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

So I was looking at the latest version of blazor application and noticed, that there is no template for blazor web app (I assume this is a goto template for the hybrid hosting model) that incorporates b2c from teh get go (unlike older wasm or server templates).

In a few tracks on github I also discovered that not everybody was able to work with that and there is a track to update documentation, but that section is not completed yet.

Does anybody know where can I get a comprehensive guide on how to actually make it work with B2C if I start from a template with no authorization (since Identity is clearly not that I need and there is no other option for now at least)? Assuming B2C tenant is in place and custom policies are working (in terms that jwt.ms can parse a token with custom claims)? Mb some useful repositories to look for and copy their Program.cs setup?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: `latest version of blazor application` which version you are looking for ?

Comment: You want to work with Blazor WASM or Blazor Server or Blazor Web App ?Pleaes confirm.

Comment: `there is no template for blazor web app` I can see .NET8 Version in Blazor Web App.Can you please be more clear about the ask.

Comment: [Image](https://i.imgur.com/ko2E285.png)

Comment: I have visual studio 2022 17.8.3 with the .net 8 SDK installed. 
The blazor templates that I have for the new blazor web app project does not contain option for azure b2c integration. 
https://ibb.co/4JGdMts

The console --auth option is also limited to Individual or None for this template.

Comment: We do not have any separate template for b2c.Select the authentication type as Microsoft identity.You will get an option to select b2c domain I'm connected services.

Comment: But there is no Microsoft Identity template for blazor united for some reason.  See all the options that are available:
https://ibb.co/gPZdM7g

Comment: Not here..check in the solution explorer connected services

Comment: OK, but it is strange that Blazor server has that option on project creation and the balzor united don't. The setup in program.cs should be identical?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256237/discussion-between-harshitha-and-pritorian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, In the template you can only see the option for Individual Accounts.

We have an option to add `Microsoft Identity Platform` from Connected Services (Code related to Authentication gets generated automatically by configuring this)- Works in all the previous versions.

[image]

[image]

- I am trying to configure the same in .NET 8 Blazor Web App.
- I have added in both Web and Client App.

***Observations when added in Web App:***

- `.csproj` is updated with the below packages.

```cs
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.13.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.13.4" />
```

***Configurations:***
[image]

- There are no changes in `Program.cs` and `appsettings.json` file.

***Observations when added in ClientApp:***

- `.csproj` file is updated with the below package.

```cs
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="8.0.0" />
```

- But I do not see any code related to `Program.cs` file in both Web and Client Apps.
- Even I do not find any documents related to Web App Authentication.
- All the docs explain about the Blazor WASM.
- AFAIK,there is no full support for the .NET 8 Blazor Web App.

Even this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-8.0) explains the Authentication only for Blazor WASM and Server Applications.

Comment: Yah, that what I also noticed. So is it safe to assume that it just don't work untill they fix this in .net 9? Or may be there is a way to grab some code related to WASM and combine it with this hybrid rendering mode to make it work?

Comment: Build a WASM App and try to configure it in Blazor Web App and check once.

Comment: @SPT it's not, but it's the closest I could find. So yah, I'll accept it. But as a solution - I just resorted to using server template of .net 7.